# How to say something is in using?

Tags: word-request

Our software has a config file. I call the one be used currently as "**in using**" one, and there is another backup one. When the "in using" one corrupted, we can replace the "in using" one with the backup one.

"In using" may be not a natural English, because I hardly find them being used.

Then, what's a natural expression for that?

Comment: Are you asking about the file **in use**?

Comment: @JasonBassford, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The correct phrase is "[in use](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/in%20use)" instead of "in using".
Hence you can say,

> The software currently in use

Answer (score 1):

There is one meaning of **live** you can use. Although the specific use here is not mentioned, similar usage is given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/live#h69837129479920):

> **live<sup>2</sup>**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **3.5** (of a ball in a game) in play, especially in contrast to being foul or out of bounds.
>   *The ball was still live and the pitcher threw it out of play.*
>
> **4** (of a question or subject) of current or continuing interest and importance.
>   *There is a question of trust and it is a live issue and we have to deal with it.*

So you can say

> I replaced the **live** version of the file with the backup.